# Spring Integration: jdbc connection not returned

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration 3.0.1 and I've noticed after some time, my jdbc pollers stop getting messages.  It appears at some point the connection is no longer being returned for some reason.  After this occurs, I notice a SQL type unknown message coming back from the jdbc message store query.
Attached is a log extract wich demonstrates a Fetch/Return and then a Fetch with the subsequent 'SQL type unknown' messages, which continue on and on after this...

```
2014-07-07 12:35:55,561 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2014-07-07 12:35:55,561 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore  - Marking messages with group key=8bdcf55e-a76a-392a-82f6-c7a956fcc572
2014-07-07 12:35:55,577 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - SQL update affected 1 rows
2014-07-07 12:35:55,577 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL update
2014-07-07 12:35:55,577 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE INT_MESSAGE_GROUP set UPDATED_DATE=? where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]
2014-07-07 12:35:55,577 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore  - Updating MessageGroup: 2051f38d-526b-3092-a156-c3d72a975f7a
2014-07-07 12:35:55,577 [task-scheduler-10] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - SQL update affected 1 rows
2014-07-07 12:35:55,577 [task-scheduler-10] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL update
2014-07-07 12:35:55,577 [task-scheduler-10] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE(GROUP_KEY, MESSAGE_ID, REGION) values (?, ?, ?)]
2014-07-07 12:35:55,577 [task-scheduler-10] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore  - Inserting message with id key=2e18bceb-db1b-c69b-cf59-eeffc211f597 and created date=2014-07-07 12:35:50.986
2014-07-07 12:35:55,592 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - SQL update affected 1 rows
2014-07-07 12:35:55,592 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2014-07-07 12:35:55,592 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL query
2014-07-07 12:35:55,592 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_BYTES, CREATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID in (SELECT MESSAGE_ID from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY = ?) and REGION=? ORDER BY CREATED_DATE]
2014-07-07 12:35:55,592 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2014-07-07 12:35:55,592 [pool-5-thread-1] TRACE org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [ac032a8d-08c6-362e-a874-453e6431c3ea], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2014-07-07 12:35:55,592 [pool-5-thread-1] TRACE org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [DEFAULT], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2014-07-07 12:35:55,608 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - SQL update affected 1 rows
2014-07-07 12:35:55,608 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL query
2014-07-07 12:35:55,608 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_BYTES, CREATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID in (SELECT MESSAGE_ID from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY = ?) and REGION=? ORDER BY CREATED_DATE]
2014-07-07 12:35:55,608 [task-scheduler-6] TRACE org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [2051f38d-526b-3092-a156-c3d72a975f7a], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2014-07-07 12:35:55,608 [task-scheduler-6] TRACE org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [DEFAULT], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
```

Sample Configuration:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="JDBCInboundChannel" query="select * from CACHE_REPOSITORY where status='X' AND CREATION_TIME + INTERVAL '15' SECOND  &lt;  SYSDATE order by CREATION_TIME" 
    channel="splitterInChannel" data-source="dataSource"  update="update CACHE_REPOSITORY set STATUS='Y' WHERE GUID IN (:guid)" row-mapper="rowMapper" 
    max-rows-per-poll="10" >
    <int:poller id="jdbcPoller" fixed-delay="1000" receive-timeout="5000" >
        <int:transactional  transaction-manager="cacheTransactionManager"/>
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter> 

<int:channel id="splitterInChannel" />  
<int:splitter id="splitter" input-channel="splitterInChannel" output-channel="aggregatorInChannel" />

<!-- Beans to support Aggregation -->       
<bean id="aggregatorBean" class="org.abc.integration.QueueItemAggregator" />
<bean id="reportTypeCorrelationStrategry" class="org.abc.integration.ReportTypeCorrelationStrategy" />
<bean id="releaseStrategry" class="org.abc.integration.ReportTypeReleaseStrategy"/>

<int:aggregator id="reportTypeAggregator" input-channel="aggregatorInChannel"
    output-channel="archiveCreationChannel" ref="aggregatorBean" method="collect"
     message-store="jdbc-messageStore" release-strategy="releaseStrategry"  
    release-strategy-method="canRelease" correlation-strategy="reportTypeCorrelationStrategry"
    correlation-strategy-method="correlate" send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true" discard-channel="errorChannel" />  

<int:channel id="archiveCreationChannel" >
    <int:queue  message-store="jdbc-messageStore" />
</int:channel>               

<!-- Endpoint responsible for creating Archive from List of Document objects -->
<bean id="cacheArchiveCreator" class="org.abc.integration.CacheArchiveCreator"/>

<int:service-activator ref="cacheArchiveCreator" method="createArchive" input-channel="archiveCreationChannel" >
    <int:poller  max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="errorChannel" >
        <int:transactional  transaction-manager="cacheTransactionManager"/>
    </int:poller>
</int:service-activator>
```

Comment: Really it isn't clear where is your issue. Can you provide the StackTrace? "pollers stop getting messages" - it might be because there is no messages in the Store.

Comment: That's a big part of the problem, There's no stack trace.  I have TRACE on for org.spring.integration.  I am testing with 100 rows in the database to poll from and then I have an endpoint which keeps track of how many I 've received.   When I start up the application, its starts polling for records. Depending on when the poller stops polling, depends on whether or not all 100 are ingested.  I have several components that utilize a jdbc message store (Aggregator, a channel, and a message store reaper).  It seems once the polling ceases, I never get any additional messages at the endpoint.

Comment: So I may poll all 100 records, but only ever get 46 at the endpoint, or I may only poll for 40 message and get even less at the endpoint.

Comment: I have added my configuration to the initial post

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with app. Or your `reaper` removes all ramaining messages or you stop poller before it has read all messages. You are the first who complains on the matter.

Try to configure different message stores for aggregator+reaper and for channels: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-message-store.

Looking to your config, as I said: use different `MessageStore` beans for aggregators and channel. Whould be better, if you'd use `JdbcChannelMessageStore` for channels.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I will try that.  Is there a default implmentation available that can be used via Xml configuration or do I need to create my own bean?  I can't find an example.  If I do need to do so, do I need to provide a query provider?

Comment: You should configure it as generic `<bean>` definition and right: the `queryProvider` is required for specific DB.

Comment: Here's where I am at.  I added the JdbcChannelMessageStore as suggested and used that for my channel.  It has the same datasource as the jdbc message store.  When both the aggregator/reaper use the jdbc message store, and the channel uses the channel specific message store, the polling quits about half way through.  If I use the in memory store for either, everything works just fine.  Could I be running out of db connections?

Comment: Looks like. Whould be better if you'd use the `pooled` DataSource.